# Word 2013 - How to create separate Table of Figures List of Tables

Tags: microsoft-word-2013, table-of-contents, microsoft-office-2016

Using the automated Caption feature (Word 2013), how do I create separate TOC's  for Table of Figures and List of Tables? They will follow below the main Table of contents (TOC) of the larger main document. Inserting table of Figures is not pulling in the hyperlink in order to build the separate List of Figures or the List of Tables.

Answer (score 0):

> how do I create separate TOC's for Table of Figures and List of Tables?

On your ToC page, below the last entry in the ToC, place your cursor where you want the Figures and/or Tables to go...

Go to References -> Insert Table of Figures -> OK

> Inserting table of Figures is not pulling in the hyperlink 
>   in order to build the separate List of Figures or the List of Tables

In the "Table of Figures" window, ensure the "Use hyperlinks instead of page numbers" box is checked before pressing the OK button

HTH